# NodeJS Express app.use want fire function with more than two arguments

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I actually working on a project running with NodeJS 18.17.1 and use Express 4.18.2.
Everything runs as expected, all routes are up, passport is doing its job but my error handling wont work as it should.

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error("something failed");
  res.status(404).send('Something broke!');
})
```

So for my understanding this should be executed on **every** error. But nothing happens. As soon as I change the function Arguments to

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use(function (req, res) {
  console.error("something failed")
  res.status(404).send('Something broke!')
})
```

the function will be called. But that is not what I would like to have.
So what am I missing, what is my mistake?

Answer (score -1):

The error handler you're using is not triggered for every error in your Express application. The reason for this is that Express handles errors in a different way than you might expect.

When Express encounters an error, it checks to see if there is a route handler for the request that is currently being processed. If there is, it will call that route handler, even if the error occurred in the middle of the route handler's execution. If there is no route handler for the request, then Express will call the error handler.

This means that your error handler is not being called for errors that occur in route handlers, because those errors are being handled by the route handlers themselves. To catch all errors, you need to wrap every route handler in a try/catch block and call next(err) if an error occurs.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    indexRouter(req, res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("something failed");
    res.status(404).send('Something broke!');
  }
});
```

This code will catch all errors that occur in the indexRouter, including errors that are caused by calling next(err).

If you want to catch errors that occur outside of route handlers, you can use the app.use() method to register an error handler that will be called for all requests. This is what you were trying to do with your original code.

Here's an example of how to register an error handler that will be called for all requests:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error("something failed");
  res.status(404).send('Something broke!');
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

This code will catch all errors, including errors that occur in route handlers.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Well, thanks for your reply, but lets say I have no route /novalidroute and try to access it, your second example should bring up the error. But this only happens if I use function(req, res,next {... with err as argument the function will be ignored.